# Search for multiple words ignoring the order in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, search, filter

I currently have a `UITextField` where I can enter a search string and it will return any of the strings in an array that contain that text, in that specific order. However, I want to make it possible to search on every word and ignore the order of the strings in the array.

```
var results = [String]()
let filterArray = ["Big green bubble", "Red bubble", "A bubble in green", "Small green bubble", "This bubble is green"]     
let textString = "green bubble" 
for i in 0 ..< filterArray.count { 
    let checkString = filterArray[i] 
    let filterRange = (checkString as NSString).range(of: textString, options: .caseInsensitive) 
    if filterRange.location != NSNotFound { 
        results.append(checkString) 
    }
}  
print(results) // returns ["Big green bubble", "Small green bubble"]
```

I wish it would also include **"A bubble in green"**  and **"This bubble is green"**, because it contains every word I am searching for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter elements from `filterArray` which contains both of these words

```
let filterArray = ["Big green bubble", "Red bubble", "A bubble in green", "Small green bubble", "This bubble is green"]
let textString = "green bubble".lowercased()
let words = textString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let results = filterArray.map { $0.lowercased() }.filter { string in words.allSatisfy { string.components(separatedBy: " ").contains($0) } }

print(results) /* ["Big green bubble", "A bubble in green", "Small green bubble", "This bubble is green"] */
```

Comment: for case insensitive `let results = filterArray.filter { string in words.allSatisfy { string.range(of: $0, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil } }`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks! I didn't notice that op'd mentioned it in his question ;)

Comment: Neat! Thank you so much, that's amazing, clean and compact!

Comment: IF I have struct and I apply this to my key title it return array of titles but I want whole model array then how can i do this sir? please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set and check if the intersection count is equal to the number of words in the query:

```
let filterArray = ["Big green bubble", "Red bubble", "A bubble in green", "Small green bubble", "This bubble is green"]
let textString = "green bubble"
let wordsSet = Set(textString.components(separatedBy: " "))
let queryResult = filterArray.filter {
    Set($0.components(separatedBy: " ")).intersection(wordsSet).count == wordsSet.count
}
queryResult  // "Big green bubble", "A bubble in green", "Small green bubble", "This bubble is green"]
```

If you need case insensitive you can map all the words to lowercase:

```
let wordsSet = Set(textString.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " "))
let queryResult = filterArray
    .map { $0.lowercased() }
    .filter {
    Set($0.components(separatedBy: " "))
        .intersection(wordsSet).count == wordsSet.count
}
```

Comment: I have now implemented Robert's answer because it is smaller and more compact, but this answer works perfectly fine as well so thanks a bunch for your input!

Comment: IF I have struct and I apply this to my key title it return array of titles but I want whole model array then how can i do this sir? please help me on this.

Comment: @YogeshPatel Would you ming posting a question with your attempt and the issues you are facing? The comments are it is not intended for questions.

Comment: sure I will Post Question and share link here. Thanks

Comment: @LeoDabus Please check this I posted question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932628/swift-full-text-search-in-tableview