# Swift Full text search in tableview

Tags: swift, search, filter, tableview, swift5

I have checked in StackOverflow Not found any valid solution of my query.

```
struct MyModel{
let title: String
let subTitle: String
let image: UIImage
}
```

Now I want to search on title and output it return mymodel filter array.
suppose this is my title array.

```
[
"Swift CollectionView Xcode 11",
"Swift UITableView Xcode 11",
"Swift UICollectionView Xcode 11",
"Objective C UITableView Xcode 11",
"Objective C CollectionView Xcode 11",
"Objective C UICollectionView Xcode 11",
]
```

**If I search `"collectionView"` then,**

"Swift UICollectionView Xcode 11", "Swift CollectionView Xcode 11" - Right

**If I search `"collectionview Objective C"` then, I want this search result and it gives me my whole array with filter**

"Objective C CollectionView Xcode 11",
"Objective C UICollectionView Xcode 11",
"Swift CollectionView Xcode 11",
"Swift CollectionView Xcode 11",

because in search it contain collectionview and objective c too. first if it contain whole string that result has to show me first then other.

I try this way but it not work

```
let stringComponent = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ")
_ = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ (str) in
            arrTemp += arrVideo.filter { (data) -> Bool in
                if data.title.lowercased().contains(str.lowercased()) && !arrTemp.contains(data){
                    return true
                }
                return false
}
```

Also checked `NSPredicate, Sort and filter` but not working for me.

Please help me! Thank You.

Comment: The main issue you are facing is sorting only right???

Comment: Yes sorting but I want result that mention in question.

Comment: Check Now Answer is edited....

Comment: Yes please check I added comment on your post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code, it will sort the arrays as per best search result.

```
  let arr =  [
            "Swift CollectionView Xcode 11",
            "Swift UITableView Xcode 11",
            "Swift UICollectionView Xcode 11",
            "Objective C TableView Xcode 11",
            "Objective C CollectionView Xcode 11",
            "Objective C UICollectionView Xcode 11",
        ]

        //Sort the array and in dictioary according to search result
        let dups = Dictionary(grouping: self.serchedArray(arr: arr, isInsideCheck: true), by: {$0}).sorted { $0.1.count > $1.1.count }

        var resultArr2 : [String] = []
        for (_, value) in dups {
            resultArr2 = resultArr2 + self.serchedArray(arr: value, isInsideCheck: false)
        }

        let dups2 = Dictionary(grouping: resultArr2, by: {$0}).sorted { $0.1.count > $1.1.count }

        //Remove duplicate values from dictionary and map to array
        let finalArray = dups2.map { $0.value[0] }
        print(finalArray)
```

This Function created for searching

```
   func serchedArray(arr : [String], isInsideCheck:Bool) -> [String] {
        var resultArr : [String] = []
        let searchText = "collectionview Objective C"
        let _ = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ").map { (str) in
            let searchedArr = arr.filter( {
                if $0.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " ").contains(str.lowercased()) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    if isInsideCheck {
                        //Check any word is contained in array's element
                        let words = $0.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " ")
                        for word in words {
                            if word.count > 1 {
                                if word.contains(str){
                                    return true
                                } else if str.contains(word) {
                                    return true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     }
                    return false
                }
            })
            //Merge the array with previous result
            resultArr = resultArr + searchedArr
        }
        return resultArr
    }
```

It will return `Objective C CollectionView Xcode 11` as first element in finalArray because it matches the all three words i.e. `collectionview`, `Objective`, `C`.

The code is lengthy because we are checking each word of searchString in each element of array,
first we check word by word then we sort.

Hope this will help you..!!

Comment: Hii it's working sometime if I search multiple time then it show me the previous value as well. can you please check and help me on that. Thanks

Comment: I search TableView and first cell it's showing me collectionview record?

Comment: whenever filter is applied firstly I remove my array then I applying your code. That's it's not repeating data.  Now it's working absolutely fine for me. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

from what I see the problem is when you separate the string from the empty string " ", so what happens is the keywords are formed

```
- collectionview
- Objective
- C
```

and cause all data to appear because "C" is a separate keyword.
is it true that I say that all the data appears?

Comment: Yaa but it has to give me record of collectionview and objective for that.